# Change the Default Empty Node Content

Tags: theming

I want to change the default empty node content of my Drupal site installation.

> [image]

I want to customize its text display as well as the "Add new content" link. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<?php
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
    unset($vars['page']['content']['system_main']['default_message']);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a view with the content listet instead of using the default node page. That allows you to customize the "No results behaviour" with custom HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Empty Front Page](https://www.drupal.org/project/empty_front_page) module as well.

This ultra lightweight module modifies this behavior to show no default content on the frontpage. Only the blocks will be displayed.

More Options

[Empty Page](https://www.drupal.org/project/empty_page) module.

[Front Page](https://www.drupal.org/project/front) module.